# Trouble with Nugets with same version

Tags: gitlab, nuget

There is a Gitlab repository that stores nugets. There is a configured CI/CD for publishing. It's okay, everything passes. The versioning system is based on tags +build-version for side branches, which can result in more than 1 Nuget build under the main tag.

At some point, packages in the source with a version under which several rebuilds were published were no longer searched.

The question is: why is this happening and how can it be fixed? Now I have only found a way with manually deleting the nuget version, rebuilding and switching to the next one, but this method does not suit me much because of the large number of nugets in one solution.

Answer (score 0):

NuGet (along with some other package managers), expect package versions to be globally unique and immutable. This allows the package manager to aggressively cache packages locally, and also allows customers to cache commonly used packages on a company internal feed if they wish.

Firstly, I'd reconsider if you really need to create packages for branches that are not either the main branch, or a release branch for lower versions that still need to be supported.

If you still "need" to create and publish packages, many people use SemVer2 pre-release versions with the branch name in the prerelease label. For example `1.2.3-zivkan-feature.5` The `.5` at the end is needed to make multiple commits built from the `zivkan-feature` branch have unique version numbers.